# JQuery draggable mouse cursor offset

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have draggable list elements which I'm able to drag into another list (in fact is not a list but a tree based on omnifaces / primefaces).

**Problem:**

I need to drag from the second list to second list (reodering element).

For this between each element of the list I have a droppable with height = 0px that I modify to 20px when my draggable overlap at this level no problem, the concern comes from the fact that when I resize the droppable, the mouse cursor shift from the draggable.

This being quite difficult to explain below picture illustrating the problem

[image]

I have tested the option cursorAt with no success if anyone have a suggestion where this shifting might come from

Comment: *"I need to drag from the second list to second list"* Why was a *second to second list* worth mentioning? Isn't it the same as just saying: "same list"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following minimal **jQuery** and **CSS** and you should be good to go.

```js
$("#second-list").sortable({
  axis: "y",
  handle: '.sortable-handle',
});

$(".removeNode").on("click", function() {
  $(this).closest("li").remove();
});
```

```css
/* QuickReset */ * {margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}

.sortable {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.sortable li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  margin: 0.5em 0;
}

.sortable-handle {
  padding: 0.3em 0.5em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  cursor: ns-resize;
  color: #888;
  transition: color 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
}

.sortable-handle::before {
  content: "⋮⋮";
}

.sortable-handle:hover {
  color: #863da6;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.removeNode {
  margin-left: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #eee;
  border: 0;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  transition: background 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
}

.removeNode:hover {
  background: #fe0306;
  color: #fff;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.removeNode::after {
  content: "✕"
}

.sortable li.ui-sortable-helper {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: inset 4px 0 0 #863da6, 0 0.1rem 0.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.sortable li.ui-sortable-placeholder {
  visibility: visible !important;
  background: #f0eefc;
  outline: 2px dashed #863da6;
  outline-offset: -4px;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="second-list" class="sortable">
  <li><span class="sortable-handle"></span> Boolean Field 1 <button class="removeNode" type="button" aria-label="Remove node"></button></li>
  <li><span class="sortable-handle"></span> Boolean Field 2 <button class="removeNode" type="button" aria-label="Remove node"></button></li>
  <li><span class="sortable-handle"></span> Boolean Field 3 <button class="removeNode" type="button" aria-label="Remove node"></button></li>
  <li><span class="sortable-handle"></span> Boolean Field 4 <button class="removeNode" type="button" aria-label="Remove node"></button></li>
  <li><span class="sortable-handle"></span> Boolean Field 5 <button class="removeNode" type="button" aria-label="Remove node"></button></li>
  <li><span class="sortable-handle"></span> Boolean Field 6 <button class="removeNode" type="button" aria-label="Remove node"></button></li>
  <li><span class="sortable-handle"></span> Boolean Field 7 <button class="removeNode" type="button" aria-label="Remove node"></button></li>
</ul>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```